# as3 - i want to run the function once i enter frame..how? onEnterFrame?

Tags: actionscript-3

how can i make this function directly run when i on the application. Now i still have to click on the pencil movie to make it activate. If u need more coding..pls let me know..HELP pls....

```
    private function PencilTool(e:MouseEvent):void
    {
        /* Quit active tool */

        quitActiveTool();

        /* Set to Active */

        active = "Pencil";

        /* Listeners */

        board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, startPencilTool);
        board.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, stopPencilTool);

        /* Highlight */

        highlightTool(pencil);
        hideTools(eraser, txt);

        ct.color = activeColor;
        shapeSize.transform.colorTransform = ct;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `PencilTool(null)` in your constructor or init method?

Answer (score 0):

Change the PencilTool function declaration to this:

```
private function PencilTool(e:MouseEvent = null):void {
```

Then, just call PencilTool(), wherever you'd like...